# CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations or didUpdateToLocation

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, deployment-target

I my iOS i am using `CLLocationManager`, but i am not sure which delegate method to use to get the location updates. There are two methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

and

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I know that i should be using the second one because the first one is deprecated but then i have set the deployment target for my app to be 6.0. So which one i should use? In the image attached [image], just beside this method

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

it says `6.0`. So what does it mean its deprecated in `iOS 6.0` or its available till 6.0. My guess is that, i should be using

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

and it should be fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any specific reason why you're still supporting iOS 6.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also faced the same issue in my old project, So I tried the following method, then working fine for me

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The delegate above is deprecated in iOS 6. Now the following should be used:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

In order to get the last position, simply get the last object of the array:

```
[locations lastObject]
```

In other words, `[locations lastObject]` (new delegate) equals `newLocation` (old delegate)

example

*iOS6 and above*

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
CLLocation *oldLocation;
if (locations.count >= 2) {
    oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-1];
} else {
    oldLocation = nil;
}
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);

}
```

*if you use in iOS6 and below add the following method also*

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
[self locationManager:locationManager didUpdateLocations:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:newLocation, nil]];
}
```

for additional reference follow this [tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/how-to-make-didupdatelocations-compatible-with-ios-5-and-ios-6/)